# Can you custom file sort in vs code?

Tags: sorting, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to custom sort files\folders in vs code? As an example if I have the following files which are in the default sort order...

```
1-safe_one.js
1-search_one.js
2-safe_two.js
2-search_two.js
3-safe_three.js
3-search_three.js
```

But I want to ignore the number-hyphen prefix so the sort order would be...

```
1-safe_one.js
2-safe_two.js
3-safe_three.js
1-search_one.js
2-search_two.js
3-search_three.js
```

Thanks

Comment: you can write your own Explorer View with whatever sorting you want

Comment: Ah as easy as that eh!?